# How to keep app running on apple watch instead of automatically going back to watch face?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm developing a WatchKit app that I want to stay in focus until the user actively selects another app or goes back to the watch using the digital crown. Just like with the built-in Workout app.

I don't want the app to be visible on screen forever, just that when I look at the watch after some minutes I want to have updated information for my app without having to go back to the app manually due to automatic switch to the watch face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can control this in your app, at least not in WatchOS 1. The only way I think this can be done is for the user to select "Resume To: Last Used App" in Settings > Activate on Wrist Raise.

Apps such as Nike+ currently advise users to change this setting before starting a run.

WatchOS 2 allows apps to register as fitness apps, that will contribute as a workout and will resume when the watch is activated / raised.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that setting, thank you! My app is "kind of" a fitness app so in that respect I might register it as a fitness app.